# regexp - must contain a word but must not contain another

Tags: regex

I need a pattern to match for a word and not match for another

## input

```
black dog
black dog and gray cat
```

I need a pattern that match all strings that contain `dog` or `house` but it must not contain `cat` or `girl`

The first input is a match but the second is not a match

## pattern

```
/dog|house|(?!cat|girl)/
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it will fill your needs

`^(?!.*(cat|girl)).*(dog|house).*`

Comment: have updated my question.. have added more keywords :)

Comment: So, what is that difficult? You already know alternation: `^(?!.*(cat|girl)).*(dog|house)`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew